# Change default prop vuetify's data table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

on `vuetify's data table` the props `page` has default value to `1` and whenever I select `items per page` then it starts from `1` but my page has default value to `0`.

```
data () {
  return {
    options: {
          page: 0,
          itemsPerPage: 40,
        },
  }
}

<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="residents"
      :options.sync="options"
      :server-items-length="totalResidents"
      :loading="loading"
      loading-text="Loading ..... Please wait"
      :footer-props="{
        itemsPerPageOptions: [5, 10, 20, 40],
        itemsPerPageText: 'Residents per page',
      }"
      :search="search"
      class="elevation-23"
    >
```

Whenever I select the `itemsPerPageOptions` to any value among the list then it starts from page 1, but my default value is 0. How do I change the vuetify's default and set to 0 ?